# Xna Particle Explosion like Geometry Wars

Tags: xna, particles, effects

I am making a game, in similar graphics display as Geometry Wars. In Geometry Wars (noticeable in the title, as well as when you blow up an enemy), there are these colorful explosions that emit, then fade away at the end. An example is [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDpeU5d-G7k). I know very little about particles. I already have an effect that will make objects glow (Bloom, if you didn't know). I would like to know if there is an Xna library that can do this effect. If not, is there code that I can use? Or some documentation that I could implement?

And also, could the code for the explosions be modified slightly to simulate the stream effect that the ship emits when it is moving around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's few particle engines, that are designed for XNA.

- [Mercury Particle Engine](http://matthew-davey.github.io/mercury-particle-engine/)
- [Dynamic Particle System Framework](http://www.xnaparticles.com/index.php)

Mercury comes with built in particle editor, where you can define and see the effects of a particle right away, realtime and after you are satisfied with results, you can import it to game.

> And also, could the code for the explosions be modified slightly to simulate the stream effect that the ship emits when it is moving around?

You don't have to modify any code. You just have to create particles that do what you want. This kind of effect would consist some single small particle, that does not move and fades away in short time. Where as explosion would start as small and start emitting fire and smoke effects and shoot smaller particles around it in sphere. It's all up to you, how the particles behave.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I've heard of this before, but I was unaware of the particle editor.